# DropCreateDatabaseAlways not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, seed

This Is my Context class

```
 public class TestContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public TestContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection")
    {

    }
    public DbSet<UserTestModel> UserTestModel { get; set; }
    public DbSet<SubscriptionTestModel> SubscriptionTestModel { get; set; }
    public DbSet<QATestModel> QATestModel { get; set; }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        Database.SetInitializer(new TestContextInitializer());
    }
}
```

and this is initializer class

```
public class TestContextInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseAlways<TestContext>
{
    protected override void Seed(TestContext context)
    {
        var user = new List<UserTestModel>{
            new UserTestModel{
                Id="1",
                UserName="Admin",
                Password="Admin123"
            },
            new UserTestModel{
                Id="2",
                UserName="User",
                Password="User123"
            }
        };
        user.ForEach(d=>context.UserTestModel.Add(d));


    }
}
```

In this code `DropCreateDatabaseAlways` not dropping database. The database does not contain any foreign key or relationship.
How to resolve this?

Comment: could you be more specific what foreign keys or relationships you want?

Comment: I do not have any foreign key or relationship. I just want to drop the and recreate database every time I call any test method

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7004701/cannot-drop-database-because-it-is-currently-in-use-how-to-fix

Comment: already Pooling is false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Global.asax file add the following:

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Database.SetInitializer<TestContext>(new TestContextInitializer());
}
```

It worked for me. This is a great video how to populate database with seed data:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XED_WgDmK4c

## EDIT

If you call it from the test method then this should do the trick:

```
Database.SetInitializer<TestContext>(new TestContextInitializer());
_dataCntx = new TestContext();
_dataCntx.Database.Initialize(true);
```

Comment: I do not have Global.asax file as I am using this context class in my test project.