# Log to database with EF Code First

Tags: c#, entity-framework, log4net

I would like to have log4net log to my database. I have added an `AdoNetAppender` as written in the [docs](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/config-examples.html) . The docs also give the definition for the Log-table to create. Since I am using Entity Framework with Code First and I am recreating the database quite often (`DropCreateDatabaseAlways`) during development, I don't want to manually create the table. I tried to create a class `Log` instead that matches the definition in the docs.

```
public class Log
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public string Thread { get; set; }
    public string Level { get; set; }
    public string Logger { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public string Exception { get; set; }
}
```

However, when using the `AdoNetAppender` I get an error that seems unrelated

> Cannot drop database "aspnet-myDb-20150625044347" because it
>   is currently in use.

but that disappears if I take out the `AdoNetAppender`.

How can I log to my database with Entity Framework code first? Thank you for any help.

Comment: You could try issuing a call such as `context.Set<Log>();` before any initialization code of `log4net`. I'm suspecting the logging framework is connecting to the database before EF attempts to drop and recreate the database resulting in the drop operation failing.

Comment: @JurgenCamilleri, this was exactly my issue, the Pooling wasn't resolving my case and when I commented out the Logger declaration at the top of my Controller (which strangely works in other older projects) Boom => Works! So I'm going to think how to implement everything for testing and production because calling the context.Set<Log>(); doesn't help ... THANK YOU!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7007818/546411) may solve your problem. The main issue is that the database still has an open connection.

short clip is to use `Pooling=false`. Being that this is in development you should not need pooling.

I know answers with links are discouraged but this is a link to another SO answer so I think we are safe here.

Hope this helps

Comment: `Being that this is in development you should not need pooling.` What will OP do when it's time for shipping?

Comment: @JurgenCamilleri, when they ship it out it will not be a drop and create always (I_HOPE) so this open connection issue should not be an issue. And setting up a transform to alter the connection string to use pooling for the release solves for the change in settings. Hope I answer your question properly

Comment: I think the issue would still persist but you may be right.

Comment: That solved the problem, log4net now logs to the database. Thanks for asking my next question, Jurgen ;o). So I should remove pooling in release? (drop create won't be necessary there)