# EF Code first database/table initialization - WHEN does it happen?

Tags: entity-framework-4, entity-framework-4.1, entity

My application is using EF code-first design and all generally works very well.

Via a private configuration file, I can specify how I would like EF to handle changes to the db schema, and so create/recreate the relevant tables as desired - the options are "never" "create", "always", "onSchemaChanged" and (for the future) "onSchemaModified".

This works well - but I am getting lost in a couple of places .....

During development, I would like to use the hook as described in 
"[Database in use error with Entity Framework 4 Code First](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5288996/database-in-use-error-with-entity-framework-4-code-first)" - but this seems to execute on EVERY run of my program"

```
 public void InitializeDatabase(Context context)
    {
        context.Database.SqlCommand("ALTER DATABASE Tocrates SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE");
        _initializer.InitializeDatabase(context); // Maybe this does nothing if not needed
        context.Database.SqlCommand("ALTER DATABASE Tocrates SET MULTI_USER")
    }
```

So .. to real my question: Is there an override that I can use to detect whether EF will ACTUALLY be trying to modify the database, so I can set this SINGLE_USER stuff when needed? And if so,  can I detect the *reason* EF it is doing so (see my list of options above) so I can log the reason for change?...

All help and suggestions are very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you have set the database intializer to `null` initializers run *always* once (per application lifetime) when you are using a context for the first time. What then actually happens depends on the initializer (your inner `_intializer`):

- For `DropCreateDatabaseAlways` and `CreateDatabaseIfNotExists` it's clear by their name what they do.
- For `DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges` there is only the question if the model changed or not. EF detects this by comparing a model hash with a hash stored in the database. You can check this yourself by calling...

  ```cs
  bool compatible = context.Database.CompatibleWithModel(true);
  ```

  ...within your custom `InitializeDatabase` and then decide based on the result if you want to send your SqlCommands or not. (Don't call this with a self-created `context` because it will cause the database to be intialized *first* before the model compatibilty is checked.) The parameter `bool throwIfNoMetadata` (which is `true` in my example) causes EF to throw an exception if the model hash in the database does not exist. Otherwise the method will return `true` in that case.
- For a custom inner initializer: Whatever your code will do.